# Thymeleaf th:field pre-processing is not working with th:each

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to display a list of objects in a table along with an option to update one of the field `marketallcoation` live. And I use thymeleaf for the purpose. So, I had to use `th:each` in combination with pre-processing capacity available in `th:field`.

In my controller class, I set the attribute as shown below:

```
model.addAttribute("marketList",supplyAllocationService.getItems());
```

And in my html page, I do something like this:

```
<table>
<tr th:each="market,iteration : *{marketList}">
                <td><span th:text="${market.date}" th:field="*{marketList[__${iteration.index}__].date}"> Date </span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${market.country}" th:field="*{marketList[__${iteration.index}__].country}"> Country </span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${market.product}" th:field="*{marketList[__${iteration.index}__].product}"> Product </span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${market.sku != null} ? ${market.sku} : 'None'" th:field="*{marketList[__${iteration.index}__].sku}"> SKU </span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${market.aggregateddemand}" th:field="*{marketList[__${iteration.index}__].aggregateddemand}"> Aggregated Demand </span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${market.aggsupply_12}" th:field="*{marketList[__${iteration.index}__].aggsupply_12}"> 12 weeks aggregated supply </span></td>
                <td><input type="text" th:value="${market.marketallcoation}" th:field="*{marketList[__${iteration.index}__].marketallcoation}"/></td>
                <td><span th:text="${market.unmetdemand}"  th:field="*{marketList[__${iteration.index}__].unmetdemand}"> Unmet demand quantity </span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${market.demandplanner}" th:field="*{marketList[__${iteration.index}__].demandplanner}"> Demand Planner </span></td>
                <td><span th:text="${market.bdmcontact}" th:field="*{marketList[__${iteration.index}__].bdmcontact}"> BDM contact </span></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

When I run the code, I get the below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'marketList[0]' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
```

As per the [docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields), no need of `th:object` if pre-processing functionality is used. I haven't used it, so I'm not sure what am I missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you're using `*{...}` syntax and/or the `th:field` attribute, then you have to use a `th:object` (they both depend on the `th:object` to function).
2. You shouldn't be using `th:field` on a `<span/>` element -- it doesn't make sense. (`th:field` sets the `name`, `id`, and `value` attributes of an element. `name` and `value` don't affect `<span />`s.)

Also, unfortunately I don't think that you can use a `List` as a form object.  So to fix your form, you need to first create a new object that has `marketList` as one of it's properties, then add that to the model instead.  Make that new object the `th:object` of your form, then the preprocessing should work for you.

```
<form th:object="${yourNewObject}>
  <table>
    <tr th:each="market, iteration: *{marketList}">
      <td th:text="${market.date}" />
      <td th:text="${market.country}" />
      <td th:text="${market.product}" />
      <td th:text="${market.sku != null} ? ${market.sku} : 'None'" />
      <td th:text="${market.aggregateddemand}" />
      <td th:text="${market.aggsupply_12}" />
      <td><input type="text" th:field="*{marketList[__${iteration.index}__].marketallcoation}"/></td>
      <td th:text="${market.unmetdemand}" />
      <td th:text="${market.demandplanner}" />
      <td th:text="${market.bdmcontact}" />
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can we update & persist the `market` object using form submission without using hidden elements?

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it answers my question in the post. However, I do have one question: "how to submit a particular `market` object while clicking the submit button?". Right now, I have to submit the entire list, loop through each object and update the values.

Comment: Yes, you can do it without using hidden elements if you set your model object using `@SessionAttributes` on the controller -- that will persist the already set information just for a single form call.  As for your second question.  Yes, you can do that, but if you are doing that why do you have all your market objects on a single form?  You probably can't use `th:field` in that case, you'll have to manually create your form with `th:name` and `th:value`.